# Creating folder and subfolders in empty directory using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I want to create folder and subfolder in an a specific directory by writing code in python.

It is important to check directory and folder if exist a specific subfolder, avoid duplicate or overwrite.

I create a loop but when directory or folder is empty it does not go to the loop or it gives me error.

I don't know how can create my folders.

Part of my code is like this:

```
# Set workspace
env.workspace = r"..\..\Test"

# Set local variables
main_folder_path = r"..\..\Test"
main_foldNam1 = "OutPutSpace"

# Execute CreateFolder
folders = os.listdir(main_folder_path)
for folder in folders:
#    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(main_folder_path, main_foldNam1)) == True:
    if arcpy.Exists(main_foldNam1):
        print main_foldNam1, "folder is Exist", "\n"
    else:  
        arcpy.CreateFolder_management(main_folder_path, main_foldNam1)

gdb_name = "CaProduc.gdb"
sub_folder1_path = r"..\..\Test\OutPutSpace"

geoDataBs = os.listdir(sub_folder1_path)
for gdb in geoDataBs:
    if arcpy.Exists(gdb_name):
        print gdb_name, " is Exist", "\n"

    else:
        arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(sub_folder1_path, gdb_name)
        print gdb_name, "\n"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-and-create-it-if-necessary for creating folders if they don't exist.

Answer (score 4):

What about using `os.path.exists` directly? Also, I would build paths using `os.path.join` which makes your code work everywhere. For creating one or more directories from a path, use `os.makedirs`... so you have everything you need :-)

Here is an example:

```
import os

main_folder_path = os.path.join('..', '..', 'Test')
main_foldNam1 = "OutPutSpace"
sub_folder1_path = os.path.join(main_folder_path, main_foldNam1)

gdb_name = "CaProduc.gdb"
gdb_path = os.path.join(sub_folder1_path, gdb_name)

# Create folder if it doesn't exist yet
if os.path.exists(sub_folder1_path):
    print("folder '{}' exists!".format(sub_folder1_path))
else:
    # create directory or directories until sub_folder1_path
    os.makedirs(sub_folder1_path)

if os.path.exists(gdb_path):
    print("'{}' exists in '{}'!".format(gdb_name, sub_folder1_path))
else:
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(sub_folder1_path, gdb_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe arcpy handles creation of folders, but I may be wrong.

Import the `os` python module, and use `os.path.exists(main_folder_path)` to check if the folder exists. If it doesn't, then use `os.makedirs(main_folder_path)` to create the folder.

Comment: looks like andsep posted their answer as I was typing mine.

Comment: Obviously you'll need to adapt the code into your existing script. The objective here wasn't to write the code for you, rather to point you to the library and functions you can use to achieve your aim.

Comment: I solve my problem with following code:                                                        folders = os.listdir(main_folder_path)
if folders == []: 
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(main_folder_path, main_foldNam1))
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(main_folder_path, main_foldNam2))
    print  main_foldNam1, " & ", main_foldNam2, "\n"
else: 
    if main_foldNam1 in folders:
        print main_foldNam1, "folder is Exist", "\n"
    else:  
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(main_folder_path, main_foldNam1))
        print main_foldNam1, "\n"